# JIRA code validation commit hook for 'git'

Tags: git, jira, commit-message

Does anyone have a git commit hook I can use that will ensure a JIRA issue number appears in the checkin message? I've got no experience driving JIRA from a git commit hook so any help would be appreciated -- working source even more so!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, make the hook executable:

```
chmod a+x .git/hooks/commit-msg
```

Append the following lines, substituting PROJECT with your project's code.

```
test "" != "$(grep 'PROJECT-' "$1")" || {
        echo >&2 "ERROR: Commit message is missing Jira issue number."
        exit 1
}
```

Comment: To check for multiple projects and to ensure that there is an issue id, use: grep -E '(PRJA|PRJB)-[[:digit:]]+'

Comment: Is it possible to make this validation on Atlassian's side? To avoid having to tell each of the the non-technical guys on the team how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# Update JIRA with git commit messages
#
# == Usage ==
#
# To update a JIRA issue, prepend the first line of your git commit
# message with the issue key and a colon:
#
#     $ git commit -m "GIT-1: Updates something"
#
# A comment will be added to the GIT-1 issue that looks something
# like:
#
#     Commit: <Hash>
#     Author: Bob Example <bob@example.com>
#     Date: Mon Jul 14 14:00:00 -0400 2008
#
#     GIT-1: Updates something
#
# To change an issue's status, append an action string:
#
#     GIT-1 resolved: Updates something
#     GIT-1 closed: Finishes this
#     GIT-1 reopen: Starting work on this
#
# To update multiple issues, separate them with a comma:
#
#     GIT-1, GIT-2: Adds comments to GIT-1 and GIT-2
#     GIT-1, GIT-2 resolved: Updates GIT-1 and resolves GIT-2
#
# == Installation ==
#
# To get this working, first install a few gems:
#
#     $ gem install soap4r
#
# Now, jira4r, which has to be pulled down from subversion:
#
#     $ svn co http://svn.rubyhaus.org/jira4r/trunk jira4r
#     $ cd jira4r
#     $ gem build jira4r.gemspec
#     $ gem install jira4r-*.gem
#
# And finally, grit, a Ruby git library.  As of today (July 14, 2008),
# the most updated fork is being maintained by Scott Chacon on github.
# For whatever reason, my attempt to install the gem directly wasn't
# working (doesn't appear to be exposed?), so I cloned and installed
# directly:
#
#     $ git clone git://github.com/schacon/grit.git
#     $ cd grit
#     $ gem build grit.gemspec
#     $ gem install grit-*.gem
#
# When the gem gets fixed, it should be a simple:
#
#     $ gem sources --add http://gems.github.com
#     $ gem install schacon-grit
#
# Now just copy/symlink/move an executable copy of this file into your
# .git/hooks directory (be sure not to overwrite an existing hook):
#
#     $ cp jira-post-receive /path/to/repo/.git/hooks/post-receive
#
# And don't forget to update some globals below.  Voila.  You should
# be in business.
#
# == TODO ==
#
#  * Get status changes with comments working.
#

require "rubygems"
require "jira4r/jira_tool"
require "grit"

# Don't forget to set these.
#
# I'd recommend creating a dedicated user in JIRA to execute these
# updates.  That user will need permissions to:
#
#  * Browse Projects
#  * Resolve Issues
#  * Close Issues
#  * Add Comments
#
# (I think that's comprehensive.)
JIRA_ADDRESS  = "http://yourserver.com/jira"
JIRA_PROJECT  = "DEMO"
JIRA_USERNAME = "user"
JIRA_PASSWORD = "password"

class JiraPostReceive
  def initialize(old_commit, new_commit, ref)
    @old_commit = old_commit
    @new_commit = new_commit
    @ref = ref

    @repo = Grit::Repo.new(".")
  end

  def jira
    unless @jira
      @jira = Jira4R::JiraTool.new(2, JIRA_ADDRESS)
      @jira.logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
      @jira.login(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD)
    end
    @jira
  end

  def run
    unless issues.empty?
      jira # Sets up access to Jira4R::V2 constants

      issues.each do |issue|
        begin
          send_comment(issue)
          send_new_status(issue) if issue[:new_status]
        rescue
          next
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Adds a comment to the JIRA issue
  #
  # Unfortunately, all comments originate from the dedicated JIRA
  # user that's used to post the comment.  It's possible to set a
  # different author for the comment, but looking one up via email
  # in JIRA doesn't seem possible without giving the user
  # administrative rights.
  def send_comment(issue)
    comment = Jira4R::V2::RemoteComment.new
    comment.author = JIRA_USERNAME
    comment.body = generate_comment(issue[:commit])

    jira.addComment(issue[:key], comment)
  end

  def send_new_status(issue)
    status_string = case issue[:new_status]
                    when "resolved" then "Resolve Issue"
                    when "closed"   then "Close Issue"
                    when "reopen"   then "Reopen Issue"
                    end

    if status = jira.getAvailableActions(issue[:key]).
        find { |a| a.name == status_string }
      jira.progressWorkflowAction(issue[:key], status.id.to_s, [])
    end
  end

  def issues
    issues = []
    issued_commits.each do |commit|
      issue_string = commit.short_message.match(/(.*?):/)[1]
      issue_string.split(",").each do |snippet|
        snippet.strip!
        snippet =~ /(#{JIRA_PROJECT}-\d+)\s?(resolved|closed|reopen)?/i
        issues << { :key => $1, :new_status => $2, :commit => commit }
      end
    end
    issues
  end

  def issued_commits
    new_commits.select do |commit|
      commit.short_message =~ /(#{JIRA_PROJECT}-\d+)(.*):/
    end
  end

  # Fetch commits that are new to the repository
  #
  # That super-piped git command makes sure that we only update JIRA
  # with commits that are new, and haven't been seen in any other
  # branches.  It's lifted verbatim from the post-receive-email hook
  # that's shipped in the git repository --
  # contrib/hooks/post-receive-email.
  def new_commits
    common_cmd = "git rev-parse --not --branches | " +
                 "grep -v $(git rev-parse #{@ref}) | " +
         "git rev-list --stdin "

    commit_ids = if branch_created?
                   `#{common_cmd} #{@new_commit}`.split
                 elsif branch_updated?
                   `#{common_cmd} #{@old_commit}..#{@new_commit}`.split
                 else
                   []
                 end

    commit_ids.map { |id| @repo.commit(id) }.reverse
  end

  def generate_comment(commit)
    <<-EOS
Commit: #{commit.id}
Author: #{commit.author.name} <#{commit.author.email}>
Date:   #{commit.authored_date}

#{commit.message}
    EOS
  end

  def branch_created?
    @ref =~ /refs\/heads/ && @old_commit =~ /^0+$/
  end

  def branch_updated?
    @ref =~ /refs\/heads/ && @old_commit !~ /^0+$/ &&
              @new_commit !~ /^0+$/
  end
end

old_commit, new_commit, ref = STDIN.gets.split
JiraPostReceive.new(old_commit, new_commit, ref).run

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I never, still, used git but a friend made SVN-Hooks, a framework for creating Subversion hooks. It was coded in perl. Maybe this help in any way.Take a look on it there:

http://code.google.com/p/svn-hooks/source/browse/trunk/t/02-jiraacceptance.t

And if you need call us, ASAP we 'll be glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

I would write a commit hook that ensures that something that *looks* like a JIRA issue number appears somewhere in the commit message. To do that, a simple regular expression match would do it:

```
/[A-Z0-9]+-\d+/
```

If you want, for extra typo-protection you can ensure that the first part matches with some project identifier that you have set up in JIRA:

```
/(ABC|XYZ|PONIES)-\d+/
```

I find there is little value in trying to make sure that the *number* part of that refers to a valid issue number. There isn't really any way to determine whether the user has entered the correct issue number (even if you manage to limit it to open issues, the user could still enter an unrelated open issue number). Users should be expected to take due care when committing code.